# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in multithreaded web crawler

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a python web crawler and make it multithreaded. The main issue I am having is running the code concurrently using the ThreadPoolExecutor library.

```
def crawl(self, url):
    for link in self.get_links(url):
      if link in self.visited:
        continue
      print("Scraping URL: {}".format(link))
      #if not visited add to visited set O(1) time
      self.visited.add(link)
      info = self.extract_info(link)
      return("word")
```

my crawl function just wants to return some string.

I have a starter function which starts the pool with a max of 2 workers:

```
  def start(self):
    job = self.pool.submit(self.crawl(self.startingUrl))
    job.add_done_callback(self.appendText)
```

The problem arises in appendText function where I am trying to convert the future object back to a string to write the string to a file:

```
def appendText(self,res):
    print("HELLO!")
    print("res = ", res.result())

    with open("Crawled.txt","w") as file:
      des = "Description: {}".format(res.result())
      key = "Keywords:{}".format(res.result())
      file.write(des)
      file.write(key)
```

I ended up getting a TypeError and have been looking to understand how to get the future object converted to a string

```
HELLO!                                                                               tures
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler/crawler.py", line 78, in <module>
    crawler.start()
  File "crawler/crawler.py", line 73, in start
    job.add_done_callback(self.appendText)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/fu
tures/_base.py", line 403, in add_done_callback
    fn(self)
  File "crawler/crawler.py", line 53, in appendText
    print("res = ", res.result())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/fu
tures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/fu
tures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/fu
tures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Where am I going wrong in this? Thank you!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

`crawl` returns a string. With how you have your code now, you're calling `crawl`, *then* giving that string  that was returned to `submit`. The pool will then attempt to execute that string you gave it as a function, thus the error.

You want to pass the function uncalled to `submit`, and have it call `crawl` for you:

```
self.pool.submit(target=self.crawl, args=(self.startingUrl,))
```

`target` is the function you want it to call, and `args` are the arguments that you want it to call the function with.

You could also use this roughly equivalent way:

```
self.pool.submit(target=lambda: self.crawl(self.startingUrl))
```

By wrapping it in a `lambda`, you can dekat execution. Prefer the first way though as `lambda` has some overhead. I'm including it here though for reference.